# awk: aggregate several lines in only one based on a field value

Tags: awk, aggregate, records

I would like to aggregate values in a file based on a specific field value which is a kind of group attribute. The ending file should have one line per group.

MWE:

```
$ head -n4 foo 
X;Y;OID;ID;OQTE;QTE;OTYPE;TYPE;Z
603.311;800.928;930;982963;0;XTX;49;comment;191.299
603.512;810.700;930;982963;0;XTX;49;comment;191.341
604.815;802.475;930;982963;0;XTX;49;comment;191.393
601.901;858.701;122;982954;0;XTX;50;comment;194.547
601.851;832.317;122;982954;0;XTX;50;comment;193.733
```

There is two groups here; 982963 and 982954.

Target:

```
$ head -n2 bar
CODE;OID;ID;OQTE;QTE;OTYPE;TYPE
"FLW (603.311 800.928 191.299, 603.512 801.700 191.341, 604.815 802.475 191.393)";982963;0;XTX;49;comment
"FLW (601.901 858.701 194.547, 601.851 832.317 193.733)";982954;0;XTX;49;comment
```

The group field is the 4 of the foo file. All other may vary.
X Y Z values of each record composing the group should be stored within the FLW parenthesis, following the same order as they appear in the first file lines.

I've tried many things ans as I'm absolutely not an expert using `awk` yet, this kind of code doesn't work at all:

```
awk -F ";" 'NR==1 {print "CODE;"$3";"$4";"$5";"$6";"$7";"$8}; NR>1 {a[$4]=a[$4]}END{for(i in a) { print "\"FLW ("$1","$2","$NF")\";"$3";"i""a[i]";"$5";"$6";"$7";"$8 }}' foo
```

Comment: You're right, but you can consider I'm totally new to `awk`. And I don't know how to perform this with `sed` which I know a little better. Anyway, I drop an example of what I've tried so far...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ awk -F ";" 'NR==1 {print "CODE;"$3";"$4";"$5";"$6";"$7";"$8}; NR>1 {a[$4]=$5";"$6";"$7";"$8; b[$4]=(b[$4]?b[$4]", ":"")$1" "$2" "$NF;}END{for(i in a) printf "\"FLW (%s)\";%s;%s\n", b[i], i, a[i]}' foo
CODE;OID;ID;OQTE;QTE;OTYPE;TYPE
"FLW (601.901 858.701 194.547, 601.851 832.317 193.733)";982954;0;XTX;50;comment
"FLW (603.311 800.928 191.299, 603.512 810.700 191.341, 604.815 802.475 191.393)";982963;0;XTX;49;comment
```

Or, as spread out over multiple lines:

```
awk -F ";" '

  NR==1 {
    print "CODE;"$3";"$4";"$5";"$6";"$7";"$8
  }

  NR>1 {
    a[$4]=$5";"$6";"$7";"$8
    b[$4]=(b[$4]?b[$4]", ":"")$1" "$2" "$NF
  }

  END{
    for(i in a)
      printf "\"FLW (%s)\";%s;%s\n", b[i], i, a[i]
  }
  ' foo
```

#### Alternate styles

For one, we can replace `";"` with `FS`:

```
awk -F";" 'NR==1 {print "CODE;"$3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7 FS $8}; NR>1 {a[$4]=$5 FS $6 FS $7 FS $8; b[$4]=(b[$4]?b[$4]", ":"")$1" "$2" "$NF;}END{for(i in a) printf "\"FLW (%s)\";%s;%s\n", b[i], i, a[i]}' foo
```

For another, the first print can also be replaced with a printf:

```
awk -F";" 'NR==1 {printf "CODE;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s",$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}; NR>1 {a[$4]=$5 FS $6 FS $7 FS $8; b[$4]=(b[$4]?b[$4]", ":"")$1" "$2" "$NF;}END{for(i in a) printf "\"FLW (%s)\";%s;%s\n", b[i], i, a[i]}' foo
```

#### Variation

If, as per the comments, the group field is the third, not the fourth, then:

```
awk -F";" 'NR==1 {print "CODE;"$3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7 FS $8}; NR>1 {a[$3]= $4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7 FS $8; b[$3]=(b[$3]?b[$3]", ":"")$1" "$2" "$NF;}END{for(i in a) printf "\"FLW (%s)\";%s;%s\n", b[i], i, a[i]}'
```

Comment: perhaps change `$5";"$6...` to `$5 FS $6 ...`

Comment: @karakfa OK.  I added a version with that to the answer.

Comment: In fact, $4 wasn't the main ID, it was a kind of a sub-group ID (on whic I should work further on...) so this is working : `awk -F";" 'NR==1 {print "CODE;"$3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7 FS $8}; NR>1 {a[$3]= $4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7 FS $8; b[$3]=(b[$3]?b[$3]", ":"")$1" "$2" "$NF;}END{for(i in a) printf "\"FLW (%s)\";%s;%s\n", b[i], i, a[i]}'`

Comment: @s.k OK.  I added that to the answer also.